# Esp32s3 I face flash encryption and secure download mode enabled help to resolve it

Tags: esp32, espressif-idf, iot-devkit

How do I disable flash encryption and secure download mode? I enabled
this, and now I am unable to flash un-encrypted flash.

I'm using the following command:

```bash
esptool.py --port /dev/ttyUSB0 --baud 115200 --chip esp32 --no-stub write_flash ...
```

I use this command, but it is not working. I see the following error:

```
A fatal error occurred: 
WARNING: Detected flash encryption and secure download mode enabled. 
Flashing plaintext binary may brick your device! 
Use --force to override the warning.
```